# Python, django, edit table with string

Tags: python, django

I don't know how set name for this question.. sorry.

I have function:

```
myFunction(request, {'Username': 'MyNewUsername', 'Sex': 'Woman', 'SexWant': 'Man'})

def myFunction(self, data):
        dataquery = UserData.objects.get(Username = "Patrycja")


        for name, key in data.items():
            dataquery.name = key

        dataquery.save()
```

Generally speaking this line: dataquery.name

name is 'Username', if I set dataquery.Username = good. But I have to do it as above

Comment: I dont know how to answer on question, without question :c

Comment: myFunction is in views.py in someone function.. def myFunction is in another file.. but doesn't matter

Comment: But seriously, what is your question? What problem are you facing?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, your query should be

```
dataquery = UserData.objects.get(username="Patrycja")
```

then be aware that the line

```
dataquery.name = key
```

sets the attribute `name` of the object.

In order to set the attributes whose name is specified in `data` you need to use `setattr`

```
for name, value in data.items():
    setattr(dataquery, name, value)
```

and since you seem to want to update [only such fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#specifying-which-fields-to-save), call save specifing which fields should be updated

```
dataquery.save(update_fields=data.keys())
```

Note: please refer to @Sayse's answer in case you need to update more than one record at a time

Comment: Note I've deleted my answer since its unclear what the op wants and it wasn't fully tested.feel free to include it in your own `UserData.objects.filter(Username="Patrycja").update(**data)`